# Jquery setting value of a td in toggled tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js script

```
$('#module-listing  > tbody  > tr').each(function(){
        $(this).toggle('show');
    });
```

How do I alter the first `td` of each `tr` displayed?

Comment: Give a read to [nth-child selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). Maybe `$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)")` can help.

Comment: Or `$(this).children().eq(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type`

`$(#module-listing  > tbody  > tr >` **td:first-of-type**`)`

```js
$('#module-listing  > tbody  > tr > td:first-of-type').each(function(){
  $(this).toggle('show');
});
```

```css
td {visibility: collapsed;}
.show {visibility: visible;}
```

```html
<table id='module-listing'>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```